NtAllocatevirtualMemory results in 0xc0000005
memory allocation through VirtualAlloc Win32 API works smoothly, however, trying to make a direct system call as provided below results in 0xc0000005 error (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION).
The code is as follows:
evasion.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" NTSTATUS myNtAllocateVirtualMemory(
    HANDLE             ProcessHandle,
    PVOID              *BaseAddress,
    ULONG              ZeroBits,
    PULONG             RegionSize,
    ULONG              AllocationType,
    ULONG              Protect
);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        LPVOID rb;
        NTSTATUS res = myNtAllocateVirtualMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), &rb, 0, (PULONG)0x1000, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        printf("STATUS: %x\n", res);
        return 0;
}

syscall.asm:
section .text
global myNtAllocateVirtualMemory
myNtAllocateVirtualMemory:
        mov r10, rcx
        mov eax, 18h
        syscall
        ret

Compiled as follows on Linux for Windows 10 x86-64:
nasm -f win64 -o syscall.o syscall.asm
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -m64 -c evasion.c -I/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/ -s -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wno-write-strings -fno-exceptions -fmerge-all-constants -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wall -shared -fpermissive
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc evasion.o syscall.o -o evasion.exe

Any suggestions are very welcomed!

Syscall indices on Windows change all the time. Are you sure you're using the correct one for your particular OS revision?

This has undefined behavior since LPVOID rb; makes rb indeterminate. Make that LPVOID rb = NULL;.

BaseAddress should be initialized (to NULL in this case), but for the crash you're casting a ULONG to a PULONG. You need to have ULONG RegionSize = 0x1000 and call NtAllocateVirtualMemory(&RegionSize). Also, I'm not 100% sure off the top of my head but RegionSize might be a SIZE_T instead of a ULONG.

The fourth parameter looks to be incorrect; it should be a pointer to a variable as defined at NtAllocateVirtualMemory function. Also, you shouldensure that your pointer rb is initialised to zero before the call.

@IInspectable , yes, I've checked it with WinDBG. Moreover, the syscall number wasn't changed since the first Windows 10 release according to this table: https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/

@TedLyngmo , unfortunately, setting rb variable to NULL doesn't change anything.

@user3467471 Yes it does. It removes one source of undefined behavior.

Try to make it work with NtAllocateVirtualMemory first.

As @Luke and @OldBoy have stated in the comments, the RegionSize parameter should be a pointer to the value. As @TedLyngmo has mentioned: the BaseAddress pointer should be initialized to NULL;
Adjusting both variables accordingly did the trick.
Here is the working code:
...

ULONG regionsize = 0x1000;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        LPVOID rb = NULL;
        NTSTATUS res = myNtAllocateVirtualMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), &rb, 0, &regionsize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        ...
}

Appreciate your help, guys. Sorry, C is not my primary language.
